# Minecraft execute syntax

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have this command running in a command block set to always active and unconditional:

```
execute as myusername if entity @e[type=chicken,distance=..5] run say chicken nearby
```

but it doesn't detect chickens.

Comment: I was able to get both of these commands to work: ```execute at username if entity @e[type=chicken,distance=..5] run say A chicken is nearby``` and ```execute as username...```, but only if I used a repeating_command_block. If I give myself a regular command_block and set it to repeating the command doesn't work.

Comment: I'm making much more progress after reading this [forum post](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/recent-updates-and-snapshots/2844075-how-to-use-the-execute-replacement-commands-for-1)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the command will run as myusername only IF the chicken is within 5 blocks of the command block. You can get it to check "at" your location instead with this:

```
execute at myusername if entity @e[type=minecraft:chicken,distance=..5] run say chicken nearby
```

Working with the execute command in 1.13 has been very challenging for me. I think the biggest problem is understanding the order of operations. It seems that "at" goes before "if" but "as" runs after "if".... But I'm speculating right now. Seems like a lot of work needs to go into understanding this very complex command.

Comment: There's also some complication with anchors, where if you don't specify "anchored" to either eyes or feet, the check defaults to a previous caller.